# Why is VS Code formatting my SCSS when I have set my config to disable auto-formatting?

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I have some SCSS code like so:

```
$theme-colors: ( 
  "primary": #0074d9,
  "danger": #ff4136,
);
```

Every time I save this file, it auto-formats it to this:

```
$theme-colors: ( "primary": #0074d9,
"danger": #ff4136,
"danger2": #ff4136,
);
```

Which is rubbish (imo).  I don't want it and have spent over an hour looking for the cause.

I disabled all SASS-oriented plugins, linters and formatters.  I changed the user settings, workspace settings, vue-project settings, I created prettierrc files so I could disable this weird formatting.  I created a local vue.config file to disable format-on-save (just to see if it affected the issue).  Nothing made any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this was due to a seemingly-unrelated formatter:

JS-CSS-HTML Formatter

I'd forgotten I had this installed (I have about 100 extensions).  Sadly, this doesn't mention SCSS or SASS anywhere in its profile.  But it *does* mention it in a changelog update in 2016.  Silly me.

I've uninstalled this extension and that's stopped the annoying formatting.  I'm sure it's good at it's job, but it isn't obvious that it's doing anything and this made the problem really hard to find.

It did make me have a much-needed clean-out of my extensions, though.

Comment: maybe you can change the settings of this extension to give the formatting you like

Comment: yeah, true, I was thinking of doing that (briefly), but I realised it was doing things I have other (more popular) extensions for.  i.e. formatting and linting, like eslint and prettier, so I just removed it.  I added this question for future reference, as it might happen on my other machines! :D  I'll accept my own answer in 2 days.

Comment: Also just found out this extension was the root of my auto formatting problem. It's disabled for the moment. Will see if I can turn it on and change some settings.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this temporarily by disabling the format on the *auto save* option.

Go to **View** -> "**Command Pallet**" and type "**Formatter Config**" and change the value to "false" of the "onSave" option to restart the visual code.

[image]

[image]

But whenever you need to format the specific page you can go to the '**Command Pallet**' and run "Formatter" command.